# Python - Mako templates - How to invalidate cache?

Tags: python, caching, mako, beaker

One of my pages has a block generated with this key:

```
<%block cached="True" cache_key="${(month, year, timezone, admin)}">
```

To invalidate a specific month/year, I loop through all the timezones/admin (about 50) calling:

```
template.cache.invalidate((month, year, timezone, admin))
```

Occasionally I'd like to invalidate this entire block. I don't want to loop through all values of month/year/timezone/admin, as this would take forever.

Is there any simple way to accomplish this?

I'm willing to invalidate the entire cache for this template.

I'm using the Beaker back-end. I hope Mako has some way to accomplish these basic tasks, but I'd be willing to use Beaker directly if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm using this Beaker specific code to clear the entire cache for a specific template:

```
kw = template.cache._get_cache_kw({}, None)
cache = self.cache_manager.get_cache(template.cache.impl.cache.id, **kw)
cache.clear()
```

I can't believe that Mako doesn't have basic support for this operation... have I overlooked something?